# What if a Repository needs to apply Business Logic to load an Aggregate?

Tags: design, c#, aggregate, repository-pattern

I have an aggregate `User` and the user has a `Score`. The `Score` of a user is calculated by queriying a bunch of different tables and running through (often very large) result sets applying some business logic. Now from a business perspective in 95% of all cases only the `Score` of a given `User` is relevant and not the data that was used to calculate it.

In my current solution I have a method on my `IUsersRepository` with the signature

```
Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(uint userId, IUserScoreCalculator userScoreCalculator);
```

The `IUserScoreCalculator` in turn has a method that takes all the data from the above mentioned different tables, does the number crunching and spits out a `Score` which then can be attached to the user.

The implementation of the `IUsersRepository` lives in my Infrastructure-Project (dealing with persisting data) whereas the implementation of the `IUserScoreCalculator` lives in my Application-Project (the business logic). The Infrastructure-Project is referencing the Application-Project.

So what's wrong?

- First I really don't like that every party requiring a `User` now needs to now how to provide an `IScoreCalculator`
- Second I really don't know... My approach just doesn't *feel right*

Some context: It is a DotNet 6 project written in C#. It uses Mediatr and in the RequestHandlers is where most of the business logic lives. It also uses Dapper as a Micro Orm in the Infrastructure project.

Comment: Is the score always used whenever a User object is retrieved?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Not always but mostly.

Comment: Well then just add another method to the repository that fetches users for a different set of use cases (while your repo should be in the Infrastructure project, its interface belongs to Application project, so in line with that, give the two methods more app-logic oriented names). Alternatively, you can have two kinds of repositories, if you want to follow the interface segregation principle (so not `IUsersRepository`, but two use case–specific interfaces, that can be implemented by two different classes, or by the same class - an implementation detail that's your choice).

Answer (score 1):

My immediate feeling was that you have the dependency reversed from what I typically see. Repositories tend to return data as requested by a use case or business class. Instead, consider passing the IUserRepository as a constructor argument to the concrete score calculator object. Each user should be passed to a `CalculateScore` method.

Doing this allows the repository to focus on serving requests for data, rather than coordinating part of a larger use case

Repositories are service classes in their own right. The service they provide is managing access to a persistent data store. There is nothing wrong with adding methods to the repository that the score calculator needs, as long as the logic is query related. Definitely avoid applying any business rules.

Your code will essentially read like this:

```csharp
IUserRepository users = // get this from wherever
var scoreCalculator = new UserScoreCalculator(users);
var user = await users.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
var score = scoreCalculator.CalculateScore(user);
```

You could provide an overload of `CalculateScore` that accepts a user Id instead of a full `User` object if that were more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Move the IScoreCalculator to a domain service and use it accordingly.
Allow the Score calculation method of User to accept that service as parameter.

```
public int GetScore(IScoreCalculator score);
```

Forget about including it inside the users repository or the user aggregate.